# How to write in a specific column

Tags: python, string

So this is pretty simple I think but I can't seem to get it working.

The objective is to simply define a function that will print a string, and the last letter of that string must be in the column `70`.

I did this.

```
def fun(s):

    print(70*' ' -len(s) , s)
```

In the attempt to create `70` spaces and subtract them to the string's length.

I get this error though:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

I know what it's telling me but can't turn it around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def fun(s):
    print(' '*(70 - len(s)) + s)
```

(if `len(s) > 70`, you will have a problem)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `rjust`: here is demo

```
>>> 'hello'.rjust(10,' ')
'     hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the format function:

```
print('{0:>70}'.format(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing:

```
' '*(70-len(s))
```

or, with a little spacing:

```
' ' * (70 - len(s))
```

This will create a string of spaces whose length is equal to `70` minus the length of the string `s`.  So, if `s` is `20` characters long, the code will make a string of `70-20` or `50` spaces.

That said, a better solution would be to use [`str.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust):

```
s.rjust(70)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> s = 'abcde'
>>> s.rjust(70)
'                                                                 abcde'
>>> len(s.rjust(70))
70
>>>
```

The `str.rjust`, `str.ljust`, and `str.center` methods (all explained in the link above) were designed specifically for tasks like this.

Comment: Thanks! I had no knowledge yet of s.rjust :b

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
print ("%70s" % s)
```

It will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
print((70-len(a))*' ',a)
```